# Is there a way to use javascript AJAX to search for all images in a folder on server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to find all images based on their extensions. (jpg, png, gif... etc) and place those images to be viewed in grid?

Comment: javascript is client side, so you can't do this without the help of a server side script. Check AJAX to see how this can be doable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with javascript alone as it's a client-side language, it doesn't "know" about the server (node.js being an exception to this).

However you can use AJAX to retreive a list of images from a PHP script or a JSP or similar.

You can read up on using PHP to get a list of files here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

And using AJAX here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

If you use jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Or with JSON too: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

You can do ajax request to server API, which should return that list for you. Server api can be done using Php, Asp.Net or Node.JS (which is javascript)